# How can I change the state of an element depending on the index array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

So I have this state:

```
  state = {
    index: 0,
    routes: [
      { key: 'first', title: 'Drop-Off', selected: true },
      { key: 'second', title: 'Pick up', selected: false },
    ],
  };
```

I need to show and hide an element depending on the selected key, if it's `true` show it,`false` hide it.

```
   const { routes } = this.state;
   {routes[i].selected && (
      <View
        style={{
          flex: 1,
          justifyContent: 'center',
          alignItems: 'center',
        }}
      >
        ...
      </View>
    )}
```

So I need to do something like (pseudo code):

`this.setState({ routes: routes[old index].selected = false, routes: routes[new index].selected = true })`

What could be the best approach?

Comment: Do you just show one view at a time, and how do you navigate between them?

Comment: @JonasWilms I am working with this library https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-tab-view but I couldn't find a way to check which view I am showing. Only the index on the state says the route I am showing.

Comment: As it seems `TabView` does manage the `View`s for you, no need to redo that.

Answer (score 2):

The pure immutable best practice way would be:

```
 this.setState(({ routes }) => ({ 
  routes: routes.map((route, index) => ({ ...route, selected: index === toSelect })),
}));
```

Comment: What is that `toSelect` is the boolean I want?

Comment: @reacting no, its an index.

Comment: So I don't get where the `toSelect` comes from. Sorry :(

Comment: `state.index` maybe?

Comment: I am getting an error `Invariant Violation: Invariant Violation: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.`

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `map()` and a `turnary` operator so that if your array is empty, it will show an alternate code.

```
// in your Class
routeChecker = (route) => {
    if (route.selected === true) {
       return (
       <div>
            {/* display the things */}
        </div>
        )
    }
}
// in your return statement inside the render()
 {/* maps the `routes` from state.routes array if the array has elements, /*}
 {/* otherwise, shows an alternate code */}
<div>
 {this.state.routes.length ?
    (<div>
        {this.state.routes.map(route => (this.routeChecker(route)))}
    </div>)
    :
    (<div>
        {/* alternate code if array is empty */}
    </div>)
}
</div>
```

Comment: This is good but where do I set `selected` to `true`? That will not happen magically. I need to set the state of `selected` to `true` then I can show what I need to show.

Comment: Oh, think I see. Is there a button or other feature that is interacted with to 'select'? In that case, I would put a function on that interaction that would change the `state` of the `route.selected` to `true`.

Comment: Not actually. My purpose is to call that function inside another function. I tried @jonas-wilms solution but I get an error : `Invariant Violation: Invariant Violation: Maximum update depth exceeded.`

Comment: You specifically asked `"I need to show and hide an element depending on the selected key"`. So, going back to my original answer then, you could use the `selected key's value` (however you access that, in the `state` or otherwise), and use that in the conditional inside `routeChecker()`.